# node_oracle on windows server

Tags: windows, oracle, node.js, windows-server

Has anyone had any success getting the node.js oracle module working on Windows Server 2008?  I can't get the library to compile; error messages seem to indicate a missing header.  I put VS2010 Express on it, as well as the Windows 7 SDK -- all with no success. The error is "C1083: can't open include stdint.h". I was curious if there had been any successful deployments.  I was able to get it built on my personal Windows 7 machine, but not on the server edition.  Any tips and/or tricks would be appreciated.

The "why" is easy -- they want it to work there.

Answer (score 0):

The readme on the GitHub repo indicates that you need to install the Oracle instant client, which appears to include the header file (occi.h) you are probably missing.

I'd start here:  https://github.com/nearinfinity/node-oracle

---

**Update:**
If you have the VS2010 Express C++ version installed on the server, it might be a path or environment variable issue. I would compare the two machines.  Is the stdint.h file on the server most likely in a path similar to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src`

An alternative is (and this is a little hacky) if the Win7 machine and your 2008 server are both 32 or 64 bit, you can install and compile it on your Win7 machine and copy over the `oracle` folder from inside the `node_modules` folder to the server.

I'm currently resetting my Oracle account to download the files on my dev box to try it myself.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I followed the instructions on the github repo.  I was able to get it working on my Windows 7 box, but not on the server box.  That is not the missing header; I'll update this with the header that was missing.

Comment: The missing header is stdint.h

Comment: You mention VS2010 Express on the server. That's the C++ version right? You could also use the All-In-One ISO download.

Comment: Joe, yes I have Visual C++ installed.  To be sure, I removed VS 2010 and installed 2012 and found the same result.  I see the stdint.h file in the path location you mentioned in 2010 and 2012.